# 802.11s with SAE vs WPA-RSN (802.11i) on a MESH network

Tags: network, wifi, wpa2

I'm investigating a protection options for a mesh network (p2p). The amount of nodes is constantly changing and possibly owned by different entities.

We are thinking between 802.11s with SAE (Simultaneous Authentication of Equals) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11s#Peer_authentication_methods and WPA-RSN https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i-2004

For what I understand, both base the trust for a mutually shared secret between two nodes and both support modern rather trustworthy crypto. The main challenge seems to be to protect and provision the shared secret in a good way. Handshake / authentication mechanism differs, but is there generally something I should know and consider when choosing between the two for a mesh network?

Additionally we are investigating different routing protocols and how to add another layer of security / trust there as well.

Please bear with me as I'm no network expert by any means.